# How do you pull a data from a second table that has the same id using PDO/php?

Tags: php, join

***DESCRIPTION***

I use the script below to displays all rows in my floradstable. I have a second table florinvtable that has identical columns. The Price column in floradstable = 0.00 whereas the Price column in florinvtable contains the real price.

```
$result = $pdo->prepare(
"SELECT floradstable.Brand, florinvtable.Price
FROM   floradstable INNER JOIN florinvtable
ON     floradstable.Barcode=florinvtable.Barcode
ORDER BY Brand");

$result->execute();

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
echo $row['Brand']." ";
echo $row['florinvtable.Price']." ";
echo "<a href='submit-ads-florida.php?deleteid=".$row['Barcode']."'>DELETE</a><br>";
}
```

***OBJECTIVE***

I would like to echo the price from florinvtable using the unique id(Barcode) both tables share.

***PROBLEM***

florinvtable.Price does not echo which leads me to believe it is echo(ing) from floradstable verses florinvtable.

***NOTE***

The current script works as is, without an error but does not pull Price FROM florinvtable

Comment: `Column 'Description' in field list is ambiguous` – try `floradstable.Description`.

Comment: @baf - I updated my question and code. I'm no longer getting an error however Price is not being pulled from florinvtable

Comment: @baf - I'm thinking the issue might reside when I use echo $row['florinvtable.Price']. I believe I defined $row for floradstable and not florinvtable, which off hand I'm not sure how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the select you defined:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare(
"SELECT floradstable.Brand, florinvtable.Price
FROM   floradstable INNER JOIN florinvtable
ON     floradstable.Barcode=florinvtable.Barcode
ORDER BY Brand");
```

the columns in the result set are just called `Brand` and `Price`.  The table reference is to fetch the correct one, not part of the name.

Try

```
echo $row['Price']." ";
```

Edit: I see you also use `$row['Barcode']`, which would not be defined by that query!  You would need

```
$result = $pdo->prepare(
"SELECT floradstable.Brand, florinvtable.Price, floradstable.Barcode
FROM   floradstable INNER JOIN florinvtable
ON     floradstable.Barcode=florinvtable.Barcode
ORDER BY Brand");
```

Comment: Hey "echo $row['Price']" worked! While I understand that I set up the INNER JOIN relationship, I'm surprised using Price worked without defining the table in the echo statement. New to the whole PDO thing, I have been scratching my head on this for more hours than I like to admit, but definately learned some new things.

Comment: `$row` is simply the result set from the SQL query.  Try running the SQL query directly and you see what the column names are in the result set.